# Printing an sqlite selection in Python 3

Tags: python, sqlite, select

So I just started working with sqlite in Python (and I am a beginner with Python as well), and I'm struggling with using the data from a Table.
Basically, I created my database but now I would like to do something with the data. I have tried just simply printing it using this function:

```
def Select():
surname = input("Whose birthdate would you like to know? (surname)\n")
print(c.execute("SELECT Birthday FROM People WHERE Surname=?", (surname,)))
```

but this is what gets printed when I call on the function.

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000020825545F10>
```

Anybody know what the fix for this is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, please make the effort to reproduce your indentation. Unindented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [fetchone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) function of the cursor to get one record or you can use [fetchall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) to get all the row of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method fetchone or fetch many.

```
print(c.fetchone())
```

or

```
print(c.fetchmany())
```

you can see the documentation [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)